# Resolver is not returning Data in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-resolver

I am new in Angular. I am trying to use resolver in my code. I have define routes for using resolver.
Here is my routing.

```
{
   path: '',
   component: AppComponent,
   resolve: {
   post: ResolverService
   }
}
```

Then I create a resolver service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Post } from './post.data';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ResolverService implements Resolve<any> {

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const post = {
      userId: 101,
      id: 101,
      title: "abc",
      body: "xyz"
    }
    return post;
  }
}
```

This resolver is not returning the post data which I am trying to access form my component. Here is my component class code.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-resolver';
  page = 1;
  pageSize = 10;

  posts;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private postService: PostService) {
  
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    
  }
}
```

Here console.log is returning an empty array. I think it should return the data I specified in the resolver class. Badly need some help. Can anyone tell me what is going on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an edge case with the `Resolve` pattern, you can't use it on the bootstrap component (AppComponent), as it's not an actual route, but the app starts from it.

If you want to preload something for the `AppComponent` you can use the `APP_INITIALIZER` instead, you can specify any number of them, and the app won't start until they are all resolved. They resolve by returning a `Promise` from them.

AppModule

```
export function resolveBeforeAppStarts(yourDataService: YourDataService) {
  return () => yourDataService.load().toPromise();
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: resolveBeforeAppStarts,
      deps: [YourDataService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

YourDataService

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class YourDataService {
  demoOnly: { userId: number; id: number; title: string; body: string };

  load = () =>
    of({
      userId: 101,
      id: 101,
      title: "abc",
      body: "xyz"
    }).pipe(
      delay(500),
      tap(x => (this.demoOnly = x))
    );
}
```

AppComponent

```
export class AppComponent {
  data = this.yourDataService.demoOnly;
  constructor(private yourDataService: YourDataService) {}
}
```

Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-txyfhd?file=src/app/your-data.service.ts